# JPanel help- Drawing rectangles

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I'm using Graphics for the first time but I have an issue where nothing is showing up besides the background (identified as Bcolor). I'm trying to make a grid with lines using fill(new Rectangle) method with color Lcolor. I ran the debugger, and there doesn't seem to be any syntax, run-time, or logic errors. Anyway to fix this? Thanks!

```
    public static void drawWindow(int Lcolor, int lineSize, int cellSize, int Bcolor){
    Graphics g = createWindow(cellSize, Bcolor, lineSize).getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    for(int i = 0; i <= (frameValues(cellSize, lineSize)[2]); i++){
        g2d.setColor(new Color(Lcolor, Lcolor, Lcolor));
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(lineSize * i + cellSize * i, 0, lineSize, frameValues(cellSize, lineSize)[1]));
        //.drawLine(xpos,ypos,xsize,ysize)
    }//for loop
    for(int j = 0; j < (frameValues(cellSize, lineSize)[3]); j++){
        g2d.setColor(new Color(Lcolor, Lcolor, Lcolor));
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, lineSize * j + cellSize * j, frameValues(cellSize, lineSize)[0], lineSize));
    }//for loop

}
```

and here is the createWindow() method:

```
public static JPanel createWindow(int cellSize, int Bcolor, int lineSize){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Evolution Of Life");
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(frameValues(cellSize, lineSize)[0], frameValues(cellSize, lineSize)[1]));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    //making it visible
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //creating panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(Bcolor, Bcolor, Bcolor));
    return panel;
}


//If you need anymore information, I'll be happy to supply.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `getGraphics` on a `JPanel`. If you want to paint to a `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method and use the `Graphics` object passed to that method as explained in the [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(){

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(...);
        g.fill(...);
    }
};
frame.add(panel);
```